# How to create GUID in vugen in java-user protocol (Load runner)?

Tags: performance-testing, uuid, guid, loadrunner, vugen

I need GUID to pass in message, for that need to Create GUID in java user protocol.

I tried and I can create GUID in web protocol but unable to find something in java protocol

Comment: http://guid.us/GUID/Java

Comment: Thanks a lot @James, this is what I am looking for.